# Python Pandas For Loop Calculation

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have pd dataframe that looks like this (`Ticker` is my index):

[image]

I want to calculate the average price for each stock, so that my final output looks like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
average_price_output = []
for ticker in tickers:
  data[ticker] = data.loc[ticker]
  average_price = data.loc[ticker]['PX_LAST'].mean()
  average_price_output.append(round(float(average_price[-1:]), 1))

model_results = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(average_price_output)), 
               columns =['Average Price']).set_index([tickers])
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.
```

The problem line seems to be: `data[ticker] = data.loc[ticker]`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you want `data.groupby(data.index).mean()`

Comment: This works, but average is just one of the functions I need to perform on price data. There are others for which I cannot just use groupby.  I need to use For-loop.

Comment: So you are saying I answered your question?

Comment: No, because I need to use For Loop.  I need to fix my code above.

Comment: I would be interested to see one of these functions that you cannot apply to a group.

Comment: Example: I need to calculate period returns and then show % of positive returns out of total

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216163/discussion-between-user10425666-and-chris).

Comment: @user10425666 I think you should either update your question with the actual question you have or start a new question thread.

Comment: You might be interested in using [.agg()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) after applying .groupby() as your other functions are applied on numbers as well.